# Ping is randomly hanging

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, ping

I have a script I put together to monitor my internet connection (provided below) for the purposes of knowing when service is restored and amassing troubleshooting data for my ISP.  The problem has the terminal window simply freeze. I traced it to the calls to the ping command by adding debug lines that spit out echo commands so I could trace progress up until the hang state.  It responds to a CTRL+C to get me back to the prompt.  I then restart the shell script, and it works for perhaps a minute or two then freezes again.  At best I can get about 5 minutes of execution time before it hangs.

My research points to ping being somewhat unstable (not what you expect out of a core utility) when it is used repeatedly.  I tried adding the `-W` timeout option, but that only seems to accelerate the problem (crashing silently in 10-30 seconds instead of 1-5 minutes).

My question is: Is there a better way to go about this?  This script is my attempt (which works well when it isn't hung up) to emulate [Net Uptime Monitor](https://netuptimemonitor.com) (which is $10 and only for Windows....boo!).

Edit: OS is Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (64-bit)

```
#!/bin/bash
alert="/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/network-connectivity-lost.oga"
logfile="netwatch.log"
interval=6
yellow=200
red=1000

function scanGoogle
{
 googleStatus=$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | tail -1 | cut -d "/" -f 5 | cut -d '.' -f 1)
 if [[ "$googleStatus" == "" ]] ; then googleStatus=0; fi
}

function scanBackbone
{
 backboneStatus=$(ping -c 1 4.2.2.2 | tail -1 | cut -d "/" -f 5 | cut -d '.' -f 1)
 if [[ "$backboneStatus" == "" ]] ; then backboneStatus=0; fi
}

function scanOpenDNS
{
 openDNSStatus=$(ping -c 1 208.67.222.222 | tail -1 | cut -d "/" -f 5 | cut -d '.' -f 1)
 if [[ "$openDNSStatus" == "" ]] ; then openDNSStatus=0; fi
}

function display
{
 echo -n "  ["
 if [ "$googleStatus" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
  googleStatus="N/A"
 else
  if [ "$googleStatus" -lt "$yellow" ]; then
   echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[36m"
   googleStatus="$googleStatus ms"
  else
   if [ "$googleStatus" -lt "$red" ]; then
    echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[33m"
    googleStatus="$googleStatus ms"
   else
    echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
    googleStatus="$googleStatus ms"
   fi
  fi
 fi
 echo -e -n "$googleStatus\\e[0m : "
 if [ "$backboneStatus" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
  backboneStatus="N/A"
 else
  if [ "$backboneStatus" -lt "$yellow" ]; then
   echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[36m"
   backboneStatus="$backboneStatus ms"
  else
   if [ "$backboneStatus" -lt "$red" ]; then
    echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[33m"
    backboneStatus="$backboneStatus ms"
   else
    echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
    backboneStatus="$backboneStatus ms"
   fi
  fi
 fi
 echo -e -n "$backboneStatus\\e[0m : "
 if [ "$openDNSStatus" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
  openDNSStatus="N/A"
 else
  if [ "$openDNSStatus" -lt "$yellow" ]; then
   echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[36m"
   openDNSStatus="$openDNSStatus ms"
  else
   if [ "$openDNSStatus" -lt "$red" ]; then
    echo -e -n "\\e[1m\\e[33m"
    openDNSStatus="$openDNSStatus ms"
   else
    echo -e -n "\\e[31m"
    openDNSStatus="$openDNSStatus ms"
   fi
  fi
 fi
 echo -e "$openDNSStatus\\e[0m]"
}

function gatherData
{
 sleep "$(echo "scale=4; $interval/3" | bc)"
 # shellcheck disable=SC2119
 scanGoogle > /dev/null 2>&1
 sleep "$(echo "scale=4; $interval/3" | bc)"
 # shellcheck disable=SC2119
 scanBackbone > /dev/null 2>&1
 sleep "$(echo "scale=4; $interval/3" | bc)"
 # shellcheck disable=SC2119
 scanOpenDNS > /dev/null 2>&1
}

function displayOutput
{
 clear
 echo -n "$(date +'%d/%m/%Y') $(date +'%T'): Internet is "
 if [[ $googleStatus -eq 0 ]] || [[ $backboneStatus -eq 0 ]] || [[ $openDNSStatus -eq 0 ]] ; then
  if [[ $googleStatus -gt 0 ]] || [[ $backboneStatus -gt 0 ]] || [[ $openDNSStatus -gt 0 ]] ; then
   echo -e -n "\\e[33mdegraded\\e[0m..."
   display
  else
   echo -e "\\e[31mDOWN\\e[0m!"
   echo "$(date +'%d/%m/%Y') $(date +'%T'): Internet is DOWN!!!" >> $logfile
   ogg123 $alert > /dev/null 2>&1
  fi
 else
  echo -e -n "\\e[32moperational\\e[0m."
  display
 fi
}

function main
{
 gatherData
 displayOutput
}

echo "$(date +'%d/%m/%Y') $(date +'%T'): Netwatch loading..."
while :
do
 main
done
```

Comment: Possibly useful: [Need an internet/broadband uptime monitor - Reddit.com/r/Ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4pfv8g/need_an_internetbroadband_uptime_monitor/)

Comment: Also you need to learn how to use `elif` statements.

Comment: @wjandrea I find else if works better from a readability standpoint as compared to elif, but thank you for pointing out that I could be saving a few bytes by using that variation instead.

Comment: As long as it is reliable, I like it like this, too.  the else - then if on a separate line.  I believe half the programmer's job is to make it not only machine-readable but maintainable also.  Also I sometimes forget where I am in an elif structure and prefer not to have to scroll back to the original if to remember how I got there.  So I like this.  BUT, this particular one can burn you in other languages like Java on the Arduino - apparently some stack gets exceeded when you have too much depth in the if structures.